# Clarification about Newline Character in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to generate JSON data where 2 paragraphs are separated by a newline character for one of my assignments.

`{ "data" : name and address separated by a new line character (\n). }`

Now, according to this description, is it possible to have a newline inserted between name and address or the character '\n' is what is expected?

When I view the JSON in my browser, it appears as `{"data":"Name  \nAddress"}`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.route('/').get(async (req,res)=>{  
  try 
  {
    let name = "Name  \n";
    let address = "Address";
    let nameAddress=name+address;
    const data = {data:nameAddress};
    return res.json(data);
}
catch (exp) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Not Found' });
  }
});
```

Is this right or should there have been a gap between name and address??

Comment: A string can contain any character.

Comment: @Pointy: What I want to know is whether a new line can be inserted between the name and address fields.

Comment: Yes, in a JavaScript string, `\n` represents a newline character. If you convert that string as part of a JavaScript object to JSON, it will work.

Comment: @Pointy : How do I do that? I tried `biography:JSON.stringify(biography)` but it did not work.

Comment: You put `\n` in the string? I mean, is that what you're asking? Like, `let str = "hello\nworld";`

Comment: @Pointy: What I'm trying to find out is whether I can display the JSON data in 2 separate lines by adding the \n character. According to your pre comment, Is there a way to display hello and world in 2 separate lines in JSON format?

Comment: If you're displaying it as HTML you have to introduce HTML markup, just as you would if you were manually typing in the content into an HTML page.

Comment: @Pointy : What if it's only JSON data, can I do it?

Comment: "JSON data" is just data. If you're putting it on a web page, you have to make it into a form that works with the DOM. You can treat the whole thing as a string and use CSS to affect the formatting, or you can transform the string into a fragment of HTML according to your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both JavaScript strings and JSON-encoded strings, the [LF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRLF) (line feed / newline) code point can be represented by the following [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences): `\n`

To create a string with two substrings (e.g. name and address) and a newline between them, you can join them on that escape sequence:

```js
const name = "Name";
const addr = "Address";

// Join with a "\n"
console.log(name + "\n" + addr);

// Or using a template literal
console.log(`${name}\n${addr}`);
```

Assigning such a string to the value of a property in an object is no different:

```js
const name = "Name";
const addr = "Address";
const nameAddr = `${name}\n${addr}`;

const obj = {data: nameAddr};

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.data);
```

Converting any serializable value to JSON is a separate concern — but JavaScript includes a method for doing that: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
const name = "Name";
const addr = "Address";
const nameAddr = `${name}\n${addr}`;
const obj = {data: nameAddr};

const json = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(json);
```

Going the other way (converting from JSON string to native JS data type) is also possible using the built-in [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
const json = `{"data":"Name\\nAddress"}`;
//                         ^
// Notice the extra escape character here in the JSON literal string.
// This escapes the following backslash character so that the resulting
// JSON-encoded string includes the newline escape sequence.
// This is needed because it's essentially a string-in-a-string!

const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(obj);

const nameAddr = obj.data;
console.log(nameAddr);
```

Here's one final example which extracts the individual name and address lines from the JSON string:

```js
const json = `{"data":"Name\\nAddress"}`;
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
const nameAddr = obj.data;

const lines = nameAddr.split("\n");

console.log(lines);

const [name, addr] = lines;

console.log(name);
console.log(addr);
```

Comment: I am able to see the separation of Name and address by a newline character when I print in the terminal but when I get the same data in the browser, the newline appears as \n. Is there a way to retain the format when returned to a browser?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668161/clarification-about-newline-character-in-json/75668376?noredirect=1#comment133493401_75668376) "_but when I get the same data in the browser, the newline appears as \n_": @gautam You'll have to provide a [mre] (like the ones in my answer) which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are returning an object that contains some strings, and the browser or any other client displays the raw data of the strings, including \s \n \t and so on.

**You can put the string in a `<pre></pre>` tag to see it formatted.**